# How to interpret $\Delta t^2$?

Tags: article-writing

In a formula such as,

$$x = x_0 + v_0 \Delta t + \frac{1}{2}a_0 \Delta t^2$$

should $\Delta t^2$ be understood as “the difference of the squares,” or “the square of the difference”?

(I suggest “the difference of the squares,” and “the square of the difference” be denoted as $(\Delta t)^2$. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: I agree, square of difference should be denoted as $(\Delta t)^2$, of the difference of the squares be denoted $\Delta (t^2)$ to avoid ambiguity. In your example though am I correct in saying it should be the square of the differences, and so $(\Delta t)^2$? It looks like a mechanics equation.

Comment: It should be $(\Delta t)^2$, not $\Delta(t^2)$

Comment: It's ambiguous. Without any context it can mean both.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you write with LaTeX. I would define it as a `mathoperator` to automatically have a disambiguating small space between  `Δ` and `t²`:

[image]

Comment: I'd say that is cutting too thin, and may not be realized by the reader. Don't you agree?

Comment: It depends on what follows the operator, just like with `log` or `sin`. For me, the case of `t²` is clear enough, but it's really a matter of personal appreciation. I tend to favour lighter notations, in general.